# Pyparsing router config: incomplete grammar with indentation

Tags: python, pyparsing

Summary: I'd like to parse configuration files which have indented blocks. These indented blocks can contain a large set of possible commands. I'd like to parse the subset of commands I have a grammar defined for, but capture the lines which don't match, and store them as text strings.

The router configuration which looks something like:

```
router bgp 1
    bgp router-id 192.168.0.1
    network 10.0.0.0/16
    neighbor 192.168.0.2 remote-as 1
    neighbor 192.168.0.2 update-source 192.168.0.1
    neighbor 192.168.0.2 next-hop-self
    neighbor 192.168.0.3 remote-as 1
    neighbor 192.168.0.3 update-source 192.168.0.1
    neighbor 192.168.0.3 next-hop-self
    neighbor 192.168.0.4 remote-as 1
    neighbor 192.168.0.4 update-source 192.168.0.1
!
router ospf
    network 1.2.3.4/30 area 0
```

This takes the form of stanza opening line + indented block + optional stanza closing line.

My problem is that router configurations can take a large number of parameters. Some I would like to parse, but for others that are unrecognised, I'd like to store as a "misc" string in my returned result, rather than skipping over them completely.

So my grammar would be to first try and match known statements such as

```
router_id = Group("bgp router-id" +  t_ipv4_address)  + EOL
```

with something like the following:

```
bgp_line = (networkline ^ neighborline ^ router_id )
bgp_data = indentedBlock(OneOrMore(bgp_line), indentStack, True)
```

I'd define the overall block like:

```
bgp_stanza = Group("router bgp" + Word(alphanums) + bgp_data )("bgp")
```

The bit I'm stumbling over is storing the lines which don't match one of networkline ^ neighborline ^ router_id.

If I define

```
misc_line =  LineStart() + Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums + "-" + "." + "/" + ":" )) + LineEnd()
```

and add this into my original grammar:

```
bgp_line = (networkline ^ neighborline ^ router_id ^ misc_line )
```

then dumping the results captures multiple lines:

```
- bgp: ['router bgp', '1', [[['bgp', 'router-id', '192.168.0.1', 'network', '10.0.0.0/16', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.2', 'remote-as', '1', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.2', 'update-source', '192.168.0.1', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.2', 'next-hop-self', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.3', 'remote-as', '1', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.3', 'update-source', '192.168.0.1', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.3', 'next-hop-self', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.4', 'remote-as', '1', 'neighbor', '192.168.0.4', 'update-source', '192.168.0.1']]]]
```

Is it possible to capture the lines that don't match one of networkline, neighborline or router_id, without capturing one of them, or am I hitting an inherent limitation of the parsing method used by PyParsing?

I've tried various combinations of SkipTo and Scanstring, but haven't found the magic combination.

Thanks.